# Cart grand total without shipping costs in Magento

Tags: php, function, magento

This is the code I have:

```
public function TOTALCODE () 
{ 
if ($parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock()) 
{ 
$amount = __(number_format(Mage::getSingleton(’checkout/session’)->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), 2, ‘,’, ‘.’)); 
$text = __(’€ %s (incl. 21% btw)’, $amount); 
$parentBlock->addLink($text, ‘checkout/cart’, $text, true, array(), 50,null,’class="top-link-cart"’); 
}
```

How do I make it show totals without the shipping costs included?

Answer (score 2):

Well, making a calculation.

`$subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal() - Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAmount()`

Answer (score 2):

It seems in Magento 1.8 is no shipping amount available in sales_flat_quote - table anymore.

I had to retrieve the totals by:

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals()
```

And check:

```
$totalKeys = array('subtotal', 'shipping', 'tax', 'discount', 'grand_total');

foreach ($totalKeys as $totalKey) {
    if (isset($totals[$totalKey])) echo $totals[$totalKey]->getData('value');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following calculation:

```
$grandTotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
$shipping = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals()['shipping']->getValue();

$grandTotalWithoutShipping = $grandTotal - $shipping;
```